# How to select all fields in SQL joins without getting duplicate columns names?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Suppose I have one table A, with 10 fields. And Table B, with 5 fields.
B links to A via a column named "key", that exists both in A, and in B, with the same name ("key").

I am generating a generic piece of SQL, that queries from a main table A, and receives a table name parameter to join to, and select all A fields + B.

In this case, I will get all the 15 fields I want, or more precisely - 16, because I get "key" twice, once from A and once from B.

What I want is to get only 15 fields (all fields from the main table + the ones existing in the generic table), without getting "key" twice.
Of course I can explicit the fields I want in the SELECT itself, but that thwarts my very objective of building a generic SQL.

Comment: FWIW It's generally a bad idea to `SELECT` more fields than you need. I don't know your use case but aside from processing and transmitting data you don't want, it can also expose fields that were added to the table later by someone who didn't know they would be visible.

Comment: That's true, but let's say it was agreed in analysis that this will not happen. So all selecting all fields from the join of A and B is what I need.

Comment: Yeah that was less a "Don't do it this way" than a "Make sure you're doing it this way for the right reason". I'd give you an answer if I could but I'm not overly familiar with PLSQL. I assume that either doing two queries (one to get field names) and/or examining the code that built the database (via reflection?) wouldn't be viable alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which RDBMS you're using it against, and how you're assembling your dynamic SQL.  For instance, if you're using Oracle and it's a PL/SQL procedure putting together your SQL, you're presumably querying USER_TAB_COLS or something like that.  In that case, you could get your final list of columns names like

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column_name)
FROM   user_tab_cols
WHERE  table_name IN ('tableA', 'tableB');
```

but basically, we're going to need to know a lot more about how you're building your dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks catherine, but doing so won't help me, because I have in the first place a list of fields that I will not know at compile time. So I am forced to use SELECT *. In any case, using DISTINCT would only work if my values where the column names, which is not the case (as in querying user_tab_cols, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Re-thinking about what I asked makes me conclude that this is not plausible. Selecting columns in a SELECT statement *picks* the columns we are interested in from the list of tables provided. In cases where the same column name exists in more than one of the tables involved, which are the cases my question is addressing, it would, ideally, be nice if the DB engine could return a unique list of fields - BUT - for that it would have to decide itself which column (and from which table) to choose, from all the matches - which is something that the DB cannot do, because it is solely dependent in the user's choice.